How to classify and solve this PDE?
Consider the following equation
$$
\partial_t f(t, x) = C_1 \partial_x f(t, x) - x g(t) f(t, x) + 2 g(t) \int_{x}^{\infty} f(t, y) dy
$$
for $t>0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, some function $g(t)>0$ and constant $C_1>0$. I have the following questions:

How would one classify this equation?
Is its solution known? If not, how would one approach solving it, is an analytical solution reasonable to obtain?


It is an "integro-differential equation". Differentiate it with respect to $x$ in order to recast it as a second-order partial differential equation.

@Abezhiko can you show me how to do that?
